# Consuming Webservice with SSL certificate in NetBeans: How to configure Truststore and KeyStrore

Tags: netbeans-6.9, webservices-client

I have generated the client Binding using NetBeans

NetBeans -> New -> Java Project

Right Click -> Webservice Client 
Here I gave my wsdl url and generated the client bindings.

**I want to configure KeyStore, TrustStore.**

I have client.cer and server.cer files with me.

If through Code also cert can be signed please share the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your NetBeans Project

> 1. Right Click on
>
>    **Project Root --> Web Service References --> service**
>      and Click on "Edit Webservice Attributes"
> 2. A popup window will appear with service tag
>      Please configure Keystore and Trustsotre  in this window by 
>      clicking on respective buttons.

Once the configuration is done   *\build\classes\META-INF\service.svc.wsdl_wsdl0.xml* file will be updated with keystore and trustore entry.

```
<wsp1:Policy wsu:Id="WS2007HttpBinding_IWebServicePolicy">
    <wsp1:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp1:All>
            <wsam:Addressing wsp1:Optional="false"/>
            <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" alias="client2" keypass="changeit" location="client.jks"/>
            <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="chageit" location="server.jks"/>
        </wsp1:All>
    </wsp1:ExactlyOne>
</wsp1:Policy>
```

Comment: Configuring Keystore and Trustsotre in Netbeans for the Project

Comment: There is no keystore and truststore option where you say...   ?